# Publicly exposed Rest class does not support post method

Tags: apex, apexrest, rest-service

I want to expose a Rest service class with a method with @HttpPost annotation.
Below is the code snippet for what I am doing

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/webhook')
global class Services {
    @HttpPost
    global static String createNewCase() {

     return 'Done';
    }
}
```

But When I call these services, this throw error

```
[
  {
    "errorCode": "METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED",
    "message": "HTTP Method 'GET' not allowed. Allowed are POST"
  }
]
```

If I make the method @HttpGet, it works

Have anyone any Idea why @HttpPost is not working?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: If you want to support both `GET` and `POST`, you need to write two separate methods annotated as such...

Comment: I Just want to support `POST`

Comment: It sounds like when you are testing you are going a GET not a POST.

Comment: @KeithC I am doing a post request and getting the error response

Comment: http://picpaste.com/Capture-yZu4O6II.PNG

Above link is the snapshot of request I am making

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the problem as I make my site secure by HTTPS and was doing a request on HTTP, So the post request was discarded.

Thanks

Comment: may i know how to resolve this?